# strange(?) module import syntax

Tags: python, import

I've come across the following code in a Python script

```
from pprint import pprint
```

why not simply `import pprint`?

Unless the module pprint contains a function called pprint which is being aliased as pprint (surely, this must be the definition of madness?)

Comment: I think you've answered your own question.

Comment: You answered your own question. And it's not madness. The method is just named pprint, and it's located in the module pprint.

Comment: Why call a module named `pprint` that contains a function `pprint` madness?  What's wrong with it?  Can you update your question to explain what you mean by "madness"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does contain a function pprint, and that is exactly what's going on. I much prefer typing pprint, not pprint.pprint, or decimal.Decimal, or datetime.datetime.now() - wouldn't you?

Comment: eloff: +1 for the use case that explained why anyone would want to do that. ok, I see whats going on. Modules provide a kind of 'namespacing' for Python objects. Still feels a bit weird though - I guess, I'll get used to it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the syntax is `from module import functions`, so the first pprint is the module name and the second the function name.

Answer (score 0):

Your belief is correct, but it is not "aliased" in any way. It is simply named `pprint`, which is no violation of any Python style guide.